# I can't find a way to delete an HTML script from a Header element

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am kind of a starter in html, css and javascript and I am trying to remove a plain script in html with no source file via a WebExtension, probably with javascript but I can't find the solution to my problem.I have looked everywhere in Stack Exchange and other simmilar blogs and forums but nothing worked

HTML Code:

```
 <script>
         const SUPPORT_BASE = "https://support.aternos.org/hc/";
         const SUPPORT_ARTICLES =   {"countdown":360026950972,"uploadworld":360027235751,"connect":360026805072,"size":360035144691,"adb  lock":360034748092,"email":360039498492,"pending":360041686352,"domains":360044623491,"deprecated":360033339752,"backups":360044837012};
</script>
```

I'm lost.Please help me.And the total HTML element is:

```
<header class="header" style="">
   <script>
       const SUPPORT_BASE = "https://support.aternos.org/hc/";
       const SUPPORT_ARTICLES = {"countdown":360026950972,"uploadworld":360027235751,"connect":360026805072,"size":360035144691,"adblock":360034748092,"email":360039498492,"pending":360041686352,"domains":360044623491,"deprecated":360033339752,"backups":360044837012};
   </script>
</header>
```

Please help me.

The website is https://aternos.org/server/

Comment: The script will execute before you can remove it

Comment: What do you mean by "remove"? Why not just edit the HTML file and remove it?

Answer (score 0):

Please define what you mean with "remove". If you just want to remove the script from the html file just remove the script text?

If you are trying to write code that will remove it when the code is running please provide the js aswell. Wont be hard with some DOM manipulation.

Comment: The html code is from a website, https://aternos.org/server/ and also, how do I close a question.As it seems, if I block the script with an adblocker then the website won't load correctly. Sorry for the fuss.